# Configurar requestTimeout direto no código

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Eu obtive um erro 502, e após muito pesquisar eu vi que aumentando o `requestTimeout` funcionaria o problema. 
Porém eu só consigo aumentar direto no `web.config`, adicionando assim na linha:

```
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Erp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" requestTimeout="360:00:00" />
```

Eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de configurar direto no código, no projeto, para quando publicar já for configurado, senão toda vez que eu publico, eu tenho que ir no `web.config` e alterar os valores.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo [Dmitry Pavlov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210876/can-you-set-request-timeout-in-asp-net-core-2-0-hosted-in-iis-from-c-sharp-code?rq=1) no StackOverflow.com:

> Não, não há como fazer isso como você descreveu. Mas, de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x), você pode simplesmente adicionar `web.config` ao seu projeto e especificar esse (e outro) valor de configuração:
>
> Se um arquivo `web.config` **não estiver presente** no projeto, o arquivo
>   será criado com o `processPath` e os argumentos corretos para configurar
>   o `ASP.NET Core Module` e movido para a saída publicada.
>
> Se um arquivo `web.config` **estiver presente** no projeto, o arquivo será
>   transformado com o `processPath` e os argumentos corretos para
>   configurar o `ASP.NET Core Module` e ser movido para a saída publicada.
>   **A transformação não modifica as configurações do IIS no arquivo**.
>
> O arquivo `web.config` pode fornecer configurações adicionais do `IIS` que
>   controlam os módulos ativos do `IIS`. Para obter informações sobre
>   módulos do `IIS` que são capazes de processar solicitações com
>   aplicativos ASP.NET Core, consulte o tópico de módulos do `IIS`.
>
> Para impedir que o SDK da Web transforme o arquivo `web.config`, use a
>   propriedade `IsTransformWebConfigDisabled` no arquivo de projeto.